# Check if a method written inside a Proc is defined?

Tags: ruby, proc, defined

For some reason I store methods in a Proc and I want to check if they are defined.

If I do : `defined? 1.+`  I get `method` in return so I know the `+` method is defined.

Now if I store the methods in a Proc : `p = Proc.new { 1.+ }`,

I want to know how i can check if the method stored in `p` is defined

I have tested `defined? p` or `defined? p.call` but it's not the attended results ...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Let the tags explain the language used, focus the title on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`defined?` is used to test if variables are defined or constants exist, not methods per-se.

For that you should use:

```
1.method(:+)
```

Where if that method doesn't exist you get a `NameError` exception. That's not the best way to test, though, instead there's a much simpler method for it:

```
1.respond_to?(:+)
```

Where if that method "responds to" that method call it will (usually) return `true`. Since Ruby is a highly dynamic programming language and methods can be made-up on the spot through `method_missing` and other tricks, this might not be 100% accurate, but it is for *pre-defined* methods.

Unfortunately once you've wrapped some valid Ruby code inside a `Proc` it's not possible to test any more if it will or won't work without executing it. This means if you have a Proc, it's basically a black box, short of delving in through tricks in the VM, but that's Ruby implementation specific.